# USB C DP Alt Mode

Tags: nvidia, usb-c

Is there any way to tell if the USB-C port on my laptop will support DP Alt Mode? I've contacted the supplier but not had any reply.

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0-25

CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m

Laptop Acer Aspire A715-42G-R7NL

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Thanks

Comment: Wait till the supplier tells you. Or maybe the supplier has a support forum.